# Generating DES Subkeys from 64b Master Key

Tags: python, encryption, des

Trying to generate DES sub-keys from master key. I have this so far. Not sure why it produces incorrect results. I have looked over everything and I'm pretty sure I have the right idea, although this is a difficult thing to tst for correctness. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something or is it just sloppy coding?

```
def main():
master = input("Hexidecimal key (omit 0x): ")

# Convert to binary
scale = 16 
num_of_bits = 64
master_bin = bin(int(master, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits)

PC1 = [57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9,
       1, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18,
       10, 2, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27,
       19, 11, 3, 60, 52, 44, 36,
       63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15,
       7, 62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22,
       14, 6, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29,
       21, 13, 5, 28, 20, 12, 4]

PC2 = [14, 17, 11, 24, 1, 5,
       3, 28, 15, 6, 21, 10,
       23, 19, 12, 4, 26, 8,
       16, 7, 27, 20, 13, 2,
       41, 52, 31, 37, 47, 55,
       30, 40, 51, 45, 33, 48,
       44, 49, 39, 56, 34, 53,
       46, 42, 50, 36, 29, 32]

# Do PC1
key_after_PC1 = []
for bit in PC1:
    key_after_PC1.append(master_bin[bit-1])

CL = []
CR = []

for j in range(28):
    CL.append(key_after_PC1[j])
    CR.append(key_after_PC1[j+28])

# Do 16 Rounds
for i in range(16):

    # Do Shifts
    if (i == 0 or i == 1 or i == 8 or i == 15):
        CL.append(CL[0])
        CL.pop(0)
        CR.append(CR[0])
        CR.pop(0)
    else:
        CL.append(CL[0])
        CL.append(CL[1])
        CL.pop(0)
        CL.pop(0)
        CR.append(CR[0])
        CR.append(CR[1])
        CR.pop(0)
        CR.pop(0)

    # Put Lists Back Together
    SK = []
    for bit in CL:
        SK.append(bit)
    for bit in CR:
        SK.append(bit)

    # Do PC2
    subkey_after_PC2 = []
    for bit in PC2:
        subkey_after_PC2.append(SK[bit-1])


    # Print Subkey as String
    subkey = ""
    for bit in subkey_after_PC2: 
        subkey += bit
    hex_subkey = hex(int(subkey, 2))
    print ("Subkey " + str(i+1) + ": " + hex_subkey)    

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no python coder, but if you fill an integer array with the input block bit index value instead of using some binary bit values you can generate something verifiable.

```
keytab -b

Table of Input Block selected key bits


  Bit  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
KS
   1  10 51 34 60 49 17 33 57  2  9 19 42  3 35 26 25 44 58 59  1 36 27 18 41
   2   2 43 26 52 41  9 25 49 59  1 11 34 60 27 18 17 36 50 51 58 57 19 10 33
   3  51 27 10 36 25 58  9 33 43 50 60 18 44 11  2  1 49 34 35 42 41  3 59 17
   4  35 11 59 49  9 42 58 17 27 34 44  2 57 60 51 50 33 18 19 26 25 52 43  1
   5  19 60 43 33 58 26 42  1 11 18 57 51 41 44 35 34 17  2  3 10  9 36 27 50
   6   3 44 27 17 42 10 26 50 60  2 41 35 25 57 19 18  1 51 52 59 58 49 11 34
   7  52 57 11  1 26 59 10 34 44 51 25 19  9 41  3  2 50 35 36 43 42 33 60 18
   8  36 41 60 50 10 43 59 18 57 35  9  3 58 25 52 51 34 19 49 27 26 17 44  2
   9  57 33 52 42  2 35 51 10 49 27  1 60 50 17 44 43 26 11 41 19 18  9 36 59
  10  41 17 36 26 51 19 35 59 33 11 50 44 34  1 57 27 10 60 25  3  2 58 49 43
  11  25  1 49 10 35  3 19 43 17 60 34 57 18 50 41 11 59 44  9 52 51 42 33 27
  12   9 50 33 59 19 52  3 27  1 44 18 41  2 34 25 60 43 57 58 36 35 26 17 11
  13  58 34 17 43  3 36 52 11 50 57  2 25 51 18  9 44 27 41 42 49 19 10  1 60
  14  42 18  1 27 52 49 36 60 34 41 51  9 35  2 58 57 11 25 26 33  3 59 50 44
  15  26  2 50 11 36 33 49 44 18 25 35 58 19 51 42 41 60  9 10 17 52 43 34 57
  16  18 59 42  3 57 25 41 36 10 17 27 50 11 43 34 33 52  1  2  9 44 35 26 49

  Bit 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
KS
   1  22 28 39 54 37  4 47 30  5 53 23 29 61 21 38 63 15 20 45 14 13 62 55 31
   2  14 20 31 46 29 63 39 22 28 45 15 21 53 13 30 55  7 12 37  6  5 54 47 23
   3  61  4 15 30 13 47 23  6 12 29 62  5 37 28 14 39 54 63 21 53 20 38 31  7
   4  45 55 62 14 28 31  7 53 63 13 46 20 21 12 61 23 38 47  5 37  4 22 15 54
   5  29 39 46 61 12 15 54 37 47 28 30  4  5 63 45  7 22 31 20 21 55  6 62 38
   6  13 23 30 45 63 62 38 21 31 12 14 55 20 47 29 54  6 15  4  5 39 53 46 22
   7  28  7 14 29 47 46 22  5 15 63 61 39  4 31 13 38 53 62 55 20 23 37 30  6
   8  12 54 61 13 31 30  6 20 62 47 45 23 55 15 28 22 37 46 39  4  7 21 14 53
   9   4 46 53  5 23 22 61 12 54 39 37 15 47  7 20 14 29 38 31 63 62 13  6 45
  10  55 30 37 20  7  6 45 63 38 23 21 62 31 54  4 61 13 22 15 47 46 28 53 29
  11  39 14 21  4 54 53 29 47 22  7  5 46 15 38 55 45 28  6 62 31 30 12 37 13
  12  23 61  5 55 38 37 13 31  6 54 20 30 62 22 39 29 12 53 46 15 14 63 21 28
  13   7 45 20 39 22 21 28 15 53 38  4 14 46  6 23 13 63 37 30 62 61 47  5 12
  14  54 29  4 23  6  5 12 62 37 22 55 61 30 53  7 28 47 21 14 46 45 31 20 63
  15  38 13 55  7 53 20 63 46 21  6 39 45 14 37 54 12 31  5 61 30 29 15  4 47
  16  30  5 47 62 45 12 55 38 13 61 31 37  6 29 46  4 23 28 53 22 21  7 63 39
```

This essentially shows the C register as input block bits followed by the D register for input block bits for the 16 selected keys (by PC2).  This table is from the Meyers/Metyas book **Cryptography** generated by a C program I wrote in the '90s, validating various tables in the book.

There's another table generated by the -s option that shows the selected keys as a function of C and D register bits.

```
keytab -s

Table of CD Reg selected key bits


  Bit  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
KS
   1  15 18 12 25  2  6  4  1 16  7 22 11 24 20 13  5 27  9 17  8 28 21 14  3
   2  16 19 13 26  3  7  5  2 17  8 23 12 25 21 14  6 28 10 18  9  1 22 15  4
   3  18 21 15 28  5  9  7  4 19 10 25 14 27 23 16  8  2 12 20 11  3 24 17  6
   4  20 23 17  2  7 11  9  6 21 12 27 16  1 25 18 10  4 14 22 13  5 26 19  8
   5  22 25 19  4  9 13 11  8 23 14  1 18  3 27 20 12  6 16 24 15  7 28 21 10
   6  24 27 21  6 11 15 13 10 25 16  3 20  5  1 22 14  8 18 26 17  9  2 23 12
   7  26  1 23  8 13 17 15 12 27 18  5 22  7  3 24 16 10 20 28 19 11  4 25 14
   8  28  3 25 10 15 19 17 14  1 20  7 24  9  5 26 18 12 22  2 21 13  6 27 16
   9   1  4 26 11 16 20 18 15  2 21  8 25 10  6 27 19 13 23  3 22 14  7 28 17
  10   3  6 28 13 18 22 20 17  4 23 10 27 12  8  1 21 15 25  5 24 16  9  2 19
  11   5  8  2 15 20 24 22 19  6 25 12  1 14 10  3 23 17 27  7 26 18 11  4 21
  12   7 10  4 17 22 26 24 21  8 27 14  3 16 12  5 25 19  1  9 28 20 13  6 23
  13   9 12  6 19 24 28 26 23 10  1 16  5 18 14  7 27 21  3 11  2 22 15  8 25
  14  11 14  8 21 26  2 28 25 12  3 18  7 20 16  9  1 23  5 13  4 24 17 10 27
  15  13 16 10 23 28  4  2 27 14  5 20  9 22 18 11  3 25  7 15  6 26 19 12  1
  16  14 17 11 24  1  5  3 28 15  6 21 10 23 19 12  4 26  8 16  7 27 20 13  2

  Bit 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
KS
   1  42 53 32 38 48 56 31 41 52 46 34 49 45 50 40 29 35 54 47 43 51 37 30 33
   2  43 54 33 39 49 29 32 42 53 47 35 50 46 51 41 30 36 55 48 44 52 38 31 34
   3  45 56 35 41 51 31 34 44 55 49 37 52 48 53 43 32 38 29 50 46 54 40 33 36
   4  47 30 37 43 53 33 36 46 29 51 39 54 50 55 45 34 40 31 52 48 56 42 35 38
   5  49 32 39 45 55 35 38 48 31 53 41 56 52 29 47 36 42 33 54 50 30 44 37 40
   6  51 34 41 47 29 37 40 50 33 55 43 30 54 31 49 38 44 35 56 52 32 46 39 42
   7  53 36 43 49 31 39 42 52 35 29 45 32 56 33 51 40 46 37 30 54 34 48 41 44
   8  55 38 45 51 33 41 44 54 37 31 47 34 30 35 53 42 48 39 32 56 36 50 43 46
   9  56 39 46 52 34 42 45 55 38 32 48 35 31 36 54 43 49 40 33 29 37 51 44 47
  10  30 41 48 54 36 44 47 29 40 34 50 37 33 38 56 45 51 42 35 31 39 53 46 49
  11  32 43 50 56 38 46 49 31 42 36 52 39 35 40 30 47 53 44 37 33 41 55 48 51
  12  34 45 52 30 40 48 51 33 44 38 54 41 37 42 32 49 55 46 39 35 43 29 50 53
  13  36 47 54 32 42 50 53 35 46 40 56 43 39 44 34 51 29 48 41 37 45 31 52 55
  14  38 49 56 34 44 52 55 37 48 42 30 45 41 46 36 53 31 50 43 39 47 33 54 29
  15  40 51 30 36 46 54 29 39 50 44 32 47 43 48 38 55 33 52 45 41 49 35 56 31
  16  41 52 31 37 47 55 30 40 51 45 33 48 44 49 39 56 34 53 46 42 50 36 29 32
```

You could note KS 16 happens to reflect PC2.  Which tells us when right shifting C and D for decryption to reverse the selected key order shifts occur after using the round key while during encryption (and as you have shown) the left shifts are applied before using the round key.  If you tabularize the round keys you'd tend to use the encode method and select them backward for decryption.

What distinguishes the keytab program from yours appears to only reside in having PC1 and PC2 permutations bifurcated for the C and D registers separately.

keytab.c:  (should be fairly highly portable)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* PC1 maps input bytes to C and D registers  */

static int PC1_C[] = {      
                57,49,41,33,25,17, 9,
                1,58,50,42,34,26,18,
                10, 2,59,51,43,35,27,
                19,11, 3,60,52,44,36
};

static int PC1_D[] = {      
                63,55,47,39,31,23,15,
                7,62,54,46,38,30,22,
                14, 6,61,53,45,37,29,
                21,13, 5,28,20,12, 4
};

/* key shift schedule */

static int shifts[] = { 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1 };


/* PC2  selects CD bits to generate selected key */

static int PC2_C[] = {
    14,17,11,24, 1, 5,
     3,28,15, 6,21,10,
    23,19,12, 4,26, 8,
    16, 7,27,20,13, 2
};

static int PC2_D[] = {
    41,52,31,37,47,55,
    30,40,51,45,33,48,
    44,49,39,56,34,53,
    46,42,50,36,29,32
};

/* The C and D arrays used to calculate the key schedule */

static int C[28];
static int D[28];

static int input[16][64];   /* Input key bits used in each KS */
static int corre[16][16];   /* correlation between keys */
static int c[28];
static int d[28];
static int cd_bits[16][48];

/* The scheduled keys, indexed by round */

static int KS[16][48];

/* Fill the key schedule */

void key_sched() {

register int index, round, shift_sched;
int temp;
int     tempcd;

/* Load C and D with input block bit values */

    for(index = 0; index < 28; index++) {
    C[index] = PC1_C[index];
    c[index] = index+1;
    D[index] = PC1_D[index];
    d[index] = index+28+1;
    }

/* Rotate C and D according to key schedule apply PC2 */

    for( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {

    /* first rotate */

    for(shift_sched=0;shift_sched < shifts[round];shift_sched++) {
        temp = C[0];
        tempcd = c[0];
        for(index = 0; index < 28-1; index++) {
        C[index] = C[index+1];
        c[index] = c[index+1];
        }
        C[27] = temp;
        c[27] = tempcd;
        temp = D[0];
        tempcd = d[0];
        for(index = 0; index < 28-1; index++) {
        D[index] = D[index+1];
        d[index] = d[index+1];
        }
        D[27] = temp;
        d[27] = tempcd;
    }

    /* Apply PC2 and store in selected key */

    for(index = 0; index < 24; index++) {
        KS[round][index] = C[PC2_C[index]-1];
        cd_bits[round][index] = c[PC2_C[index]-1];;
        KS[round][index+24] = D[PC2_D[index]-28-1];
        cd_bits[round][index+24] = d[PC2_D[index]-28-1];
    }
    }
}

void key_input() {
int index;
int round;

     for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++ )
         for (index = 0; index < 48; index++) {
             input[round][KS[round][index]] = 1; /* mark those used */
         }
}

void key_core() {
int key1,key2;
int keybit;
    for (key1 = 0; key1 < 16; key1++)  
        for (key2 = 0; key2 < 16; key2++) {
            corre[key1][key2] = 0;
        for (keybit = 0; keybit < 64; keybit++) 
            if (input[key1][keybit] & input[key2][keybit])
                corre[key1][key2]+= 1;
        }
    printf("\n\nKS  ");
    for (key1 = 0; key1 < 16; key1++)
        printf("%2d ",key1+1);
    printf("\n\n");

    for (key1 = 0; key1 < 16; key1++) {
        printf("%2d  ",key1+1);
        for (key2 = 0; key2 < 16; key2++) {
            if (corre[key1][key2] == 48)
                printf("   ");
            else
                printf("%2d ",corre[key1][key2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

#define MAX_STR 2048
int main (argc,argv) 
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
int round;
int keybit;
extern int getopt();
extern char *optarg;
extern int optind, opterr;
char *ofile;
int input_block = 0;
int input_bit = 0;
int input_corre = 0;
int cd_bit = 0;
int i;

    while ( (i=getopt(argc,argv,"cibso:")) != -1 )  {
        switch (i) {
        case 'c':
            input_corre = 1;
    break;
        case 'i':
            input_bit = 1;
    break;
        case 'b':
            input_block = 1;
    break;
    case 's':
        cd_bit = 1;
    break;
        case 'o':
            ofile = optarg;
            if(freopen(optarg,"w",stdout) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR:%s, can't open %s for output\n",
                        argv[0],optarg);
                exit(-1);
            }
        break;
        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s [-i][-c][-b][-o outfile] \n",argv[0]);
            fprintf(stderr,"\t-i shows which input block bits are used in each round\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"\t-c shows number of key bits in common between rounds\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"\t-b outputs key tables shown as input block bits\n"); 
            fprintf(stderr,"\t-s outputs key tables shown as CD reg bits\n"); 
            exit (-1);
        break;
        }
    }

    key_sched();

    if (cd_bit) {
        printf("\nTable of CD Reg selected key bits\n\n");
        printf("\n  Bit ");
        for ( keybit = 0; keybit < 24 ; keybit++)
            printf("%2d ",keybit+1);

        printf("\nKS\n");

        for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {
            printf("  %2d  ",round+1);
            for (keybit = 0; keybit < 24; keybit++) 
                printf("%2d ",cd_bits[round][keybit]);
        printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n  Bit ");
        for ( keybit = 24; keybit < 48 ; keybit++)
            printf("%2d ",keybit+1);

        printf("\nKS\n");

        for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {
            printf("  %2d  ",round+1);
            for (keybit = 24; keybit < 48; keybit++) 
                printf("%2d ",cd_bits[round][keybit]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n%c",'\014');
    }


    if (input_block) {
        printf("\nTable of Input Block selected key bits\n\n");
        printf("\n  Bit ");
        for ( keybit = 0; keybit < 24 ; keybit++)
            printf("%2d ",keybit+1);

        printf("\nKS\n");

        for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {
            printf("  %2d  ",round+1);
            for (keybit = 0; keybit < 24; keybit++) 
                printf("%2d ",KS[round][keybit]);
        printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n  Bit ");
        for ( keybit = 24; keybit < 48 ; keybit++)
            printf("%2d ",keybit+1);

        printf("\nKS\n");

        for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {
            printf("  %2d  ",round+1);
            for (keybit = 24; keybit < 48; keybit++) 
                printf("%2d ",KS[round][keybit]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n%c",'\014');
    }

    key_input();

    if (input_bit) {
        printf("\n  Bit ");
        for ( keybit = 0; keybit < 24 ; keybit++)
            printf("%2d ",keybit+1);

        printf("\nKey\n");

        for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {
            printf("  %2d  ",round+1);
            for (keybit = 0; keybit < 24; keybit++) 
                printf(" %c ",(input[round][keybit])?'X':'.');
        printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n  Bit ");
        for ( keybit = 24; keybit < 48 ; keybit++)
            printf("%2d ",keybit+1);

        printf("\nKey\n");

        for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {
            printf("  %2d  ",round+1);
            for (keybit = 24; keybit < 48; keybit++) 
                printf(" %c ",(input[round][keybit])?'X':'.');
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n  Bit ");
        for ( keybit = 48; keybit < 64 ; keybit++)
            printf("%2d ",keybit+1);

        printf("\nKey\n");

        for ( round = 0; round < 16; round++) {
            printf("  %2d  ",round+1);
            for (keybit = 48; keybit < 64; keybit++) 
                printf(" %c ",(input[round][keybit])?'X':'.');
        printf("\n");
        }
    }    
    if (input_corre) 
        key_core();
    exit (0);
}
```

There's also a javascript DES implementation floating around that's been disabled to prevent it from using arbitrary keys in an educational environment.  Capturing the page you can actual undo the disable allowing it to use arbitrary keys.  See http://people.eku.edu/styere/Encrypt/JS-DES.html.  The value here is in showing off internal values for each round.

[A copy of JS-DES.html with writable keys can be found at http://dpades.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simu_js/JS-DES.html, the project home page (http://code.google.com/p/dpades/) says it's GPLv2.]

Comment: Thank you so much. The website you posted enabled me to check my existing code. Turns out it was right!

Comment: It looked right without understanding the bit about python 'pop' and 'append' which looked consistent.  The hardest part of any implementation in DES is understanding where yours goes wrong.  I used to use a copy of the source for the original BSD libcrypt DES which output the same thing.